# How can I match part of a string with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Say there's a string like

> "... width=600 height=1200 ...".

I want to get string after `"width="` and before `" "`, which is `600`.

How can I do this?

Comment: My guess is that what you are doing can be done in a rather nicer way.  Could you give a little more context for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to limit the width size, when users input the YouTube video source.

Comment: @Deckard Can you give an example of what the user might input, and what elements you'd want to modify?

Comment: When user post a youtube source, the width shouldn't be over 600px. So, `<DIV><EMBED height=311 type=application/x-shockwave-flash width=600 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/0O2Rq4HJBxw allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent"></EMBED>` is ok, while `<DIV><EMBED height=311 type=application/x-shockwave-flash width=700 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/0O2Rq4HJBxw allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent"></EMBED>` is not okay.

Comment: So I need to check this value, before submit.

Comment: Ah, youtube source is in TEXTAREA element!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a regular expression with the [*match()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function:

```
var str = "... width=600 height=1200 ...",
    width = str.match(/\bwidth=(\d+)/);

if (width)
    alert(width[1]); 
    //-> 600
```

The regular expression provided looks for a word boundary (`\b`) followed by the literal string `width=`, followed by 1 or more digits, which are also captured as a sub-expression (`(\d+)`).  This sub-expression capture is added to the array returned by match.

Comment: Thank you. I barely know regular exp. But I think I have to learn it.

Comment: @Deckard: There are plenty of tutorials out there, just make sure you find ones that are compatible with JS regular expressions.  The MDC docs for RegExp are pretty good too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions to parse this:

```
var matches = "... width=600 height=1200 ...".match(/width=(\d+)/);
if (matches) {
    alert(matches[1]);
}
```

You should consider posting more information, though. You are probably trying to solve a problem that can be avoided, like others stated in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with lonesomeday, in that it feels like there's a nicer solution here if you could give us some more context, but that said, I'll give my two cents.

You could try something like this:

```
var str = "width=600 height=1200";
$('<div ' + str + '>').attr('width');
```

This means that you're leveraging the HTML parser to get a sensible result out of your string.

---

Update with the info you posted in the OP comments:

You want to check this string for the width attribute:

```
<DIV><EMBED 
    height=311 type=application/x-shockwave-flash
    width=700 src=http://www.youtube.com/v/0O2Rq4HJBxw
    allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"
    wmode="transparent">
</EMBED></DIV>
```

In this case, I'd actually strongly recommend using the above approach.

```
var str = "<DIV><EMBED height ... etc";
$(str).find('embed').attr('width');
```

I'll save you the obligatory link to the "Don't use a regex to parse HTML" rant/freakout answer, but it definitely applies here.

Comment: My first thought was to downvote, but this is actually pretty clever.

Comment: Thank you. Next time I'll give you more details about my problems. And for this question, I'm trying to limit the width size of YouTube link source.